# Compressed corner in my prints

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, calibration

I'm getting issues with any print in the specific corner throughout different and unrelated prints. The specific corner comes out compressed.

I have tried to take pictures to illustrate the issue:

[image: back view]
[image: side view]
[image: angeled view]

Any ideas on what to look at?

Printer: Creality CR-10

Answer (score 2):

This is a very well known issue that is caused by insufficient adhesion. The corners curl up during printing.

You should increase the adhesion by:

- cleaning the bed (I use water and soap, others use isopropyl alcohol)
- better leveling,
- correct nozzle to build plate distance (dragging paper method),
- using a brim or so-called mouse ears in your design,
- increased the heated bed temperature, or
- use of an adhesive like hair spray or glue stick ([not any type will work](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11183/5740)) or specific sprays that are created for this purpose (e.g. 3DLAC, Dimafix, etc.)

---

*Some people used tape on the build plate for adhesion, but I'm **not a fan of tape**. [Not all tapes work](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/why-does-the-painters-tape-have-to-be-blue). Tape needs to be applied correctly, prepared (sanded), etc. This is much more cumbersome than applying a little spray over the build plate. It can be successfully used on PEI, Buildtak (clones), glass and on the [bare aluminium bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/should-you-use-hairspray-on-a-metal-bed-3d-printer/6861#6861).*

Comment: Also consider cleaning the printbed prior to each print (e.g. with isopropyl alcohol). I've had several prints fail because of people touching the printbed with greasy fingers.

Comment: @Rik Good point, I use water and soap, but not regularly, I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Also, since the OP seems to be having problems at the same part of multiple prints, it may be that his bed is warped so that one part of the bed is lower than the rest.

Comment: I strongly recommend a brim, with brim gap (newish Cura feature) of around 0.25 mm to make it fully removable without damage to the model while fixing this type of peeling off the bed pretty much 100%. It doesn't need to be a wide brim; just 3 lines suffices for me.